# How to overwrite to the older version Ubuntu in dual-boot desktop?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, 19.04

I had Ubuntu 19.04 on my DUAL-BOOT desktop but it gets stuck in the "purple" screen. Thus, I decided to install the newer version Ubuntu without losing my old data. When I tried to install the new version, i get this notice

[image: Installation type]

If i choose the first option, Will It keep my data ? and Are there any affects to my Windows 10 ?

Will it just install on the Ubuntu partition or it will install over Windows partition ?

Comment: Backup your data from both Windows and Ubuntu. Then choose the first. It will delete your Ubuntu partition and all the data saved in Ubuntu. It should not have any effect on Windows, but who knows? Back up Windows data as well to be safe.

Comment: Only the 'something else'  (ie. manual partitioning) will preserve your data, and then it'll depend on what options you select later (ie. if you format any partitions, those partitions will not have data preserved).  It is my opinion you want 'something else', to select your existing partitions (ie. something else is manual so you can control it) ensuring you don't have format ticked, it'll note your installed packages, erase system directories, install, add back your *added* packages (if available) without touching data (unless you formatted), then ask to reboot.  Backup first anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you installed Ubuntu. If you created a root partition only, you'll have to backup your data before reinstalling your OS, which could be through the First option or through "Something else" (I mean, if that's the case, you'll necessarily need to erase your data). However, If you have a /home partition where your data is stored, then you should choose "Something else" and do the proper installation steps.

It won't be too much different from the first time you installed your system. There you'll be able to pick the same partitions already in use by your Ubuntu and set them as you wish, since you'll have the choice to either format or not your /home partition (in your case, you'll have to uncheck "format" checkbox for your current /home partition).

The link below might be helpful. It carefully explains the possibilities.

https://itsfoss.com/replace-linux-from-dual-boot/

Comment: Even if /home is on the root partition, something-else and no-format will NOT erase data as only system directories are erased. This will impact server users (as many server applications store program configs in system directories!) but desktop applications store their data in /home/$USER and that will not be touched unless format is selected.

Comment: I assumed he meant personal info on a personal desktop, but didn't think of other possibilities. Thanks for the remark! :)

Comment: thank you guys, i backup my data successfully